# Infinitive construction of a relative clause - "to be" or "to have been"?

Tags: grammar

Let's consider the following sentence:

> This is the first white rhinoceros which has been born in captivity

Would the corresponding construction with an infinitive be:

> This is the first white rhinoceros to be born in captivity

or

> This is the first white rhinoceros to have been born in captivity?

Is the second sentence grammatically correct? If so, I'd suppose that sentence comes closer in meaning.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Your first (non-infinitival) example is stylistically inelegant. The two infinitival alternants you suggest are to be preferred. There's little if any difference in meaning.